# Extracting elevation value (z-value) from 3D polygon at given point with QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, elevation, extract, z-value

I am working with surfaces that limit the growth of buildings or structures near airports, for this I have modeled a series of regulatory surfaces that define the maximum permissible limit that an object can be projected in the airspace, these surfaces have different slopes and dimensions, and they even overlap each other, in that sense I need to extract the elevation of the 3D surface when it intersects a point or polygon in space.

I am trying with the "aggregate" function, because I need to obtain this value automatically for a mobile application, but I have not had any results, suddenly there are other functions in QGIS to solve this problem.

The data I have is a polygon type layer with all the 3D surfaces from which the elevation value should be extracted and another layer of points that represent objects that are projected in the airspace.

[image]

Comment: This is how I would approach to solve it.
First, in order to extract elevation value from one layer to another, there is a need for a data source. The data source would contain the elevation value (z value). If i understood the question, which of the layers contains the elevation data/value?

Comment: The layer that contains the elevation data is a polygon layer, this layer is a regular geometric figure with elevations with respect to mean sea level, the points when digitized must take the value of the elevation of the polygon layer when they intersect with this and return the elevation value in a field of the point layer automatically.